# Is using GUID on a static file resource enough protection in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, authorization, static-files

Im following along with the documentation from asp.net regarding serving static files:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1

In my blazor-serverside app; when a user uploads a file the file **is private to him and anyone who knows the resource by fully qualified name**. The file is "sharable" by i.e mail, meaning an e-mail will fire to him and his "followers". In the e-mail the image he uploads is available using
`<img src="Basepath/staticfiles/SomeGuid_filename.bmp">`.
Now the e-mail client can display the image directly without authorization.

This is exactly what I want. Since im using a guid on the resource it will be difficult to find static resources by guessing, so im assuming this will give the same protection as an access token on an API. Is this correct? Directory browsing is turned off by default.

The UseStaticFiles stuff is in front of app.UseAuthentication();app.UseAuthorization(); which will serverthe static files to anyone who know the name of a static file.

```
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //file system
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(resourceSettings.ResourceDirectory),
            RequestPath = new PathString(resourceSettings.ResourceStaticFilesUrl)
        });
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationhub");

        });
```

So the main question is: is using a guid on the static resource enough protection, or the same as an access token on an API? Is there anyway for someone to query the list of static files when directory browsing is turned off? Am im doing this "correctly" or are there alternatives?

Comment: "im assuming this will give the same protection as an access token on an API"...no not at all. Requiring a (presumably secret) token would prevent someone from accessing the resource even after they have discovered the URL - unless they provide the token in the request of course. Whereas your version is what is often known as "security by obscurity" whereby you simply hide the resource and hope it won't be discovered. There's no actual protection there, it's just that it's not easy to find. But it sounds like that's what you want anyway, so there's no issue really.

Comment: P.S. With directory browsing turned off, there's no way for anyone to get a list of files, that's correct. However it's not impossible that a search engine might eventually index it. There are ways to try and prevent that if it's a problem.

Comment: `Now the e-mail client can display the image directly without authorization.` And the email is thus your weak point. If I can intercept the email then I have access to the resource. Why do you want it specifically to be accessible as a static file? Why not have the file accessible via a secured URL?

Comment: @ADsyon not fully understanding the difference really. This is also why im asking i guess. :) Is the problem that im not invalidating the url? Url+accesstoken != Url+GuidStaticResource is weird

Comment: @njwiils the only reason was to be able to show the content as <img> in e-mail to the users who receives it.

Comment: "not invalidating the url"...what do you mean by "invalidate" exactly?

Comment: Is the problem that the url is "Long-lived"?

Comment: I don't know. Only you can tell us if that's a problem for you or not. The URL will always work once you've created it , unless you change something on your server. Are you wanting to put a time limit on how long it will be available for?

Comment: "Url+accesstoken != Url+GuidStaticResource is weird"...not really. An access token is supposed to be basically private. It's not part of the URL - it's usually sent in the request header. So it wouldn't be logged in HTTP logs, or sniffable over the wire (assuming HTTPS is used). Whereas a GUID is part of the URL, and it uniquely identifies that specific resource. In contrast an access token generally gives overall permission to access the whole API, not to a single item.

Comment: Basically in your scenario, your image is publicly accessible, it's just that you're not advertising it very much. But if you require an access token, it's inaccessible to anyone who didn't have the token, even if they know the URL. Imagine you open a very small restaurant. You don't want to be overwhelmed with customers so you just tell a few people about it. But soon they tell their friends, and word spreads. Anyone who knows the address can turn up and eat. But if you say no-one can come in without knowing the password on the door, then just knowing the address isn't enough to gain entry.

Comment: Now of course someone could steal the password, or it could be accidentally revealed, but that requires extra effort, and so any random stranger is far less likely to be able to walk in off the street.

Comment: @ADyson When using access token correctly and passed as part of the post request then its not logged etc. That is totally different from a static url. I accept that, and agree that using accesstoken is in fact not the same as a static "obscure" url. :) Thanks!